# Web scraping a class that only comes after a specific class

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

This is a simplified sample of an html that I want to scrape:

```
<td class='goal'>
    <div>
        <span>
            <span>
                <span class='cellValue'>
```

I want to scrape the value that is under class 'cellValue', but there are a lot of those in my html that are not related. I want to scrape only those that appear after class 'goal'.

Can anyone tell me how to do that? I'm using puppeteer and i've tried the following:

I've tried things like:

```
let goals = document.querySelectorAll('.goal > .cellValue')

let goals = document.querySelectorAll('.goal.cellValue')
```

Nothing helped. Help please :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector should be `.goal .cellValue`:

```
let goals = document.querySelectorAll('.goal .cellValue')
```

`.goal > .cellValue` would only select elements with the class `.cellValue` whose direct parent element had the class `.goal`.  Because there are several ancestors in between the two in your case, you want the more expansive `.goal .cellValue` query.

Also, `.goal.cellValue` selects elements that contain both classes. Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm getting an array of {}. The number of items is correct which is awesome, but why are all the items empty?

Comment: What is the content of those spans with the cellValue class?

Comment: 4.00. Some sort of float.

Comment: @NimrodShai can you show your code? Hard to answer without more detail.